# QRCoder Html Base64 lengthy URI need to shorten

Tags: c#, uri, qr-code, projects-and-solutions, qrcoder

I am trying to link a lengthy HTML URI to QR code generated through QRCoder, but it gives the below error:

> QRCoder.Exceptions.DataTooLongException: The given payload exceeds the maximum size of the QR code standard. The maximum size allowed for the choosen paramters (ECC level=L, EncodingMode=Byte) is 2953 byte.

Can anyone give me alternative solution or some fix which can help here, I am searching a way to either create QR code with lengthy URI or to shorten the URIs.
Below is the code used:

```
QRCodeGenerator qRCodeGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
var htmlUri = ConvertToDataUri(qrCodeText.outputHtml, "text/html");
QRCodeData qRCodeData = qRCodeGenerator.CreateQrCode(htmlUri, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.L);
QRCode qRCode = new QRCode(qRCodeData);
Bitmap bitmap = qRCode.GetGraphic(10);
byte[] BitMapArray = bitmap.BitmapToByteArray();
string QrUri = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(BitMapArray));
return Ok(QrUri);
```

---

EDIT:

Please use the below URI of the QR code generated from above code where I hard coded a small url instead of URI to explain:
data:image/png;base64,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

Comment: Where did you get this code? A URI does not contain QR code.

Comment: @jdweng I am generating a QR which has a URI as data.

Comment: The data is never in the URI.  A HTTP Request/Response has three parts 1) URI 2) HTTP Headers 3) HTTP body.  The QR-Code is never in the URI.

Comment: @jdweng what you're saying is opposite to what I explained, the QR is containing the URI.

Comment: @jdweng please check the above QR URI, that I have added for your reference

Comment: The QR-Code is fine.  It is a base64 string.  What do you plan to do with it?  Do you plan to make it an attachment to a HTTP Request, A Mail Attachment, A Webpage, or a body of an email?  A URI is only the IP Address (or name) of a server, it does not include the HTTP headers or Body.  Do you have a sample of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I took the base64 string from the qr code you posted and put into a file test1.txt.  Then ran code to uncompress the string and saved into a png file.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string qrText = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\test1.txt");
            byte[] image = Convert.FromBase64String(qrText);
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\temp\qr.png", image);
 

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the image for the URI `https://shubhamshshaw.github.io/businessPamplet/`

[image]

There is no issue with the QR code.  The issue is what you are doing with the base64 string.

Comment: https://shubhamshshaw.github.io/businessPamplet/ is a URL not a URI, what I am trying to do is add a big base64 HTML URI in a QR, which gives error because QRCoder cannot take big size data to create QR code.

Comment: A QR code is capable of encoding a maximum of 2953 bytes of data, 4296 alphanumeric characters, 7089 numeric characters, or 1817 Kanji characters (character set according to JIS X 0208)

Comment: That's what is my problem.

Comment: There is no work around to max number.

Comment: is there a work around to reduce the size of a base64 string.

Comment: No.  Base64 is a standard algorithm.

Comment: So, is there any alternate solution to my problem? Can I use some other way to pass data in URL other than base64 where it can be take minimum URL length.

Comment: You are exceeding the specification limits and you have to reduce the size 1) Reduce the URL length 2) Reduce the resolution of the image 3) Reduce the number of alphanumeric characters.